# using greek letters with subscripts for labels in rpart.plot or fancyRpartPlot?

Tags: r, rpart, rattle

I have the following MWE:

```
library(rpart.plot)
library(rpart)

set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(nu = c(rnorm(mean = 1, n = 100), rnorm(mean = 2, n = 50)), rho = c(rnorm(n = 50),rnorm(sd=2,n=100)), cl = c(rep("TRUE",100), rep("FALSE",50)))
names(df)[-3] <- c(expression(nu),expression(rho))
```

The above did not work, so I used the unicode fonts:

```
names(df)[-3] <- c("\u03BD","\u03C1")
```

So I use the following from the `rpart` package and then plot using `rpart`.

```
tree <- rpart(cl~., data = df)
rpart.plot(tree, type = 4, extra = 0, branch.lty = 3, box.palette = "RdYlGn")
```

I get:

[image: rpart.plot without subscripts that works]

However, my next objective is to add subscripts to `nu` and `rho`.

I tried:

```
names(df)[-3] <- c(expression("\u03BD"[1]) , expression("\u03C1"[2]))

tree <- rpart(cl~., data = df)
rpart.plot(tree, type = 4, extra = 0, branch.lty = 3, box.palette = "RdYlGn")
```

But

```
rpart.plot(tree, type = 4, extra = 0, branch.lty = 3, box.palette = "RdYlGn")
```

gives:
[image: rpart.plot with subscripts]

The same issue arises  with `rattle`'s ``fancyRplot`:

```
 fancyRpartPlot(tree, caption = NULL)
```

that yields:

[image: fancyRpartPLot with subscript]

Is there a way to include subscripts in `rpart.plot`
or `fancyRpartPlot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rpart.plot()` doesn't seem to support the `expression()` notation. However, you can use the Unicode ₁ ([subscript 1](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2081)) and ₂ ([subscript 2](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2082)) characters, `\u2081` and `\u2082`.

```r
names(df) <- c("\u03BD\u2081", "\u03C1\u2082", "cl")
tree <- rpart(cl~., data = df)
rpart.plot(tree, type = 4, extra = 0, branch.lty = 3, box.palette = "RdYlGn")
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you! One more question: do you know how to use italicized `nu` or `rho`?

Comment: @user3236841 I'd just use the italic Unicode characters: `names(df) <- c("\U1D708\u2081", "\U1D70C\u2082", "cl")`. Note you need a capital `\U` as the codepoint is longer than four hex digits.

Comment: Thanks again! I was not aware that the capital `\U` is how we get the codepoint to be longer than four hex digits.